How to Vectorize Timezone Offset Calculation in Pandas DatetimeIndex for Improved Performance?
I'm working with a Pandas DataFrame that utilizes a DatetimeIndex with timezone information. My objective is to compute the timezone offset (in hours) for each timestamp and store these offsets in a new column within the DataFrame.
Current Approach:
Currently, I'm using the .map() function combined with a lambda to extract the UTC offset from each timestamp:
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame setup
timestamps = pd.date_range('2024-01-01 00:00:00', '2024-12-31 23:59:59', freq='5min', tz='Europe/Brussels')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': range(len(timestamps))}, index=timestamps)

# Computing timezone_offset using .map() and lambda
df['timezone_offset'] = df.index.map(
    lambda x: x.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 3600 if x.utcoffset() else 0)

print(df['timezone_offset'][:5])

OUTPUT
2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    1.0
2024-01-01 00:05:00+01:00    1.0
2024-01-01 00:10:00+01:00    1.0
2024-01-01 00:15:00+01:00    1.0
2024-01-01 00:20:00+01:00    1.0

Issue:
While this method accurately populates the 'timezone_offset' column, it becomes significantly slow as the size of the DataFrame grows. Processing 100,000 entries takes a considerable amount of time, which is a bottleneck for larger datasets or real-time applications.
Objective:
I aim to vectorize the timezone offset calculation to enhance performance and reduce computation time. Ideally, I want to avoid using row-wise operations like .map() with lambda functions, which are known to be inefficient with large datasets.

related: Get UTC Offset in hours from Datetimeindex Pandas Series localtime

One fast solution:
df["offset"] = df.index.tz_localize(None) - df.index.tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None)
df["offset"] = df["offset"].dt.total_seconds() / 3600



doing the calculation in Unix time nanoseconds should give a bit of extra performance; (df.index.tz_localize(None).astype(int) - df.index.tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None).astype(int))/3_600_000_000_000. Some might add "at the cost of readability".

Indeed. The OP try takes around 0.900 s. My solution takes 0.010 s. And 0.007 s with your extra tip.
